# Draw line with oblique border

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

How to draw line with oblique border like this:
[image: oblique border]

I drew only a normal line:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 30.f);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor personalBlue].CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.f, 0.f);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,self.bounds.size.width, 0.f);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: You won't magically get ends like that by _stroking_. One obvious approach:Draw a parallelogram and _fill_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CAShapeLayer:

```
class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.redraw
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.layer.bounds

        let width = self.layer.frame.size.width
        let height = self.layer.frame.size.height

        let path = CGMutablePath.init()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50))

        mask.path = path

        self.layer.mask = mask

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = self.bounds
        shape.path = path
        shape.lineWidth = 3.0
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        self.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }


}
```

The result is this:

[image]